# How do I properlly install Python 3.7.1 and kivy

Tags: python, kivy, command-prompt

I have been trying to install and test Kivy on Python 3.7.1 it keeps on returning this error in the command prompt:

> `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ductile (from versions:) No matching distribution found for ductile.`

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? What command(s) is that output from? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Try doing this in VS Code terminal rather than [tag:command-prompt]

Answer (score 0):

I installed kivy by using the following  commands.

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install kivy
```

If this does not work for you I recommend you install all these modules in PyCharm.